# How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?

Tags: ssh, terminal, gnu-screen, job-control, disown

I have a running program on a SSH shell. I want to pause it and be able to unpause its execution when I come back.

One way I thought of doing that was to transfer its ownership to a screen shell, thus keeping it running in there.

Is there a different way to proceed?

Comment: See also [Can I nohup/screen an already-started process?](http://serverfault.com/questions/24425) and [Resume command running in dropped SSH session](http://serverfault.com/questions/115998), which mention several ptrace-based solutions not (currently) mentioned here.

Comment: From questions like http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4039/13496 I'm hearing about _retty_ and _neercs_.  Hmmm... wonder if there's smth like a "_screen_ here" layer before I run a process next time should I lose the top terminal in the future, that will make it easy to snap back in the stdin/out/err

Comment: The secondary/implicit issue in this question I can't fathom is...why did the shell choose to disown a suspended job when there is a _newer/just launched_ one in _background_ that doesn't even need/wait for stdin?  This is the treatment I've gotten used to so don't know what went different here...

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can revoke “ownership” of the program from the shell with the [`disown`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html#index-disown) built-in:

```
# press Ctrl+Z to suspend the program
bg
disown
```

However this only tells the shell not to send a `SIGHUP` signal to the program when the shell exits. The program will retain any connection it has with the terminal, usually as standard input, output and error streams. There is no way to reattach those to another terminal. ([Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen) works by emulating a terminal for each window, so the programs are attached to the screen window.)

---

It is possible to reattach the filedescriptors to a different file by attaching the program in a debugger (i.e. using [`ptrace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace)) and making it call `open`, `dup` and `close`. There are a few tools that do this; this is a tricky process, and sometimes they will crash the process instead. The possibilities include (links collected from answers to [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell) and [Can I nohup/screen an already-started process?](https://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process)):

- [grab](http://www.ucc.asn.au/~dagobah/things/grab.c) (and the more ambitious [cryopid](https://code.google.com/p/cryopid/))
- [neercs](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/neercs)
- [reredirect](https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect/)
- [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr)
- [retty](http://pasky.or.cz/~pasky/dev/retty/)

Comment: `disown` removes the process from the job-control list.

Comment: Why not [`disown -h`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/625436/819417)?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman That leaves the job in the shell's job table, but what's the advantage of that?

Comment: @Gilles: so you can still `fg` or `kill` it, and see if it ends on its own.

Comment: What mentioned utilities work with a group of processes (e.g. `bzcat a.bz2 | grep text`)? Man for `reptyr` says that it does not support moving the processes with children.

Comment: @dma_k In this example, you'd only need to move `grep`'s output.

Answer (score 85):

Using GNU `screen` is your best bet.

Start screen running when you first login - I run `screen -D -R`, run your command, and either disconnect or suspend it with `CTRL-Z` and then disconnect from screen by pressing `CTRL-A` then `D`.

When you login to the machine again, reconnect by running `screen -D -R`. You will be in the same shell as before. You can run `jobs` to see the suspended process if you did so, and run `%1` (or the respective job #) to foreground it again.

Comment: I think this doesn't answer the question. The question begins with "*I have a program running*". This answer assumes it's not running yet…

Comment: yes he clearly wrote he wants to get it into a screen session :-)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, or at least it doesn't answer this question which is linked: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171250/how-to-move-a-background-job-from-one-terminal-tab-to-another

Comment: This answer is great, as you need some preparation, if you want to it right, at least the next time

Answer (score 76):

To move a process between terminals or to reattach a disowned, you can use e.g. [reptyr](http://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/).

Comment: Yeah that saved it, thanks! I read the author's website how it works better than similar or older tools eg. for ncurses programs.

Comment: This is awesome; it should solve a friend's predicament of constantly losing her work by running it straight in ssh and then needing to get on a train.  *"Oops, forgot to use screen.  Again."*

Comment: +1 Although the accepted `screen` answer is of course ideal, it doesn't actually answer the question, which specifically requests a way to _move_ a currently running process to `screen` or the like. Also see this answer: http://serverfault.com/a/284795

Comment: Absolute live saver. Allowed me to re-attach to running apt dist-upgrade that was sitting on waiting for user confirmation.

Comment: Can be installed using `APT` on Debian based distros: `sudo apt install reptyr`.

Answer (score 27):

My favorite solution is using `tmux`, you could detach the session, and re-attach it in another terminal.

When you detached from previous session, you can safely close the terminal; later use `tmux attach` to get back to the session, even if you logged out.

Comment: you also can share your session with ur friend and use multiple windows and panes and so much more! love it ^_^

Comment: example of using please?

Answer (score 24):

There's also a small utility called [retty](http://pasky.or.cz/~pasky/dev/retty/) that lets you reattach running programs to another terminal.

Answer (score 20):

I don't use it regularly, but [neercs](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/neercs) claims to support this. It's a `screen`-like program with miscellaneous fancy features like better pane management, but the main thing it offers is the ability to import a process into a pane

Comment: Interesting. It does play dirty (`ptrace`), but it doesn't just manipulate the file descriptors, it forks the process. It's able to grab `find /`, but crashed an interactive bash.

Comment: @Gilles I can't remember how it went when I tried, but it doesn't have a great reputation, I'm told it fails pretty regularly

Answer (score 13):

If you just want to pause it and restart afterwards, you can use `kill` with `STOP` or `CONT` signal.

At first find out the processes PID with

```
$ ps aux
```

Then send the signals to that PID listed to the process

```
$ kill -STOP <PID>

$ kill -CONT <PID>
```

Answer (score 11):

"injcode" from ThomasHabets seems to be exactly the thing I need:

https://github.com/ThomasHabets/injcode

The injcode program allows arbitrary code to be injected into a running 
process, whether or not you knew beforehand and were running screen or tmux

From the README:

> ### Example 1: move irssi from one terminal to another
>
> Maybe move it into a screen.
>
> First start irssi in one terminal.
>
> Run injcode in another terminal:
>     $ injcode -m retty
>
> Irssi should now be moved to the second terminal, including having a new 
>   controlling terminal.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

1. `bg` the process
2. `jobs -l` find process number
3. `tmux` start shell window manager
4. `reptyr -L PROCESSNUMBER`

---

`reptyr`'s `-L` was necessary to get this to work:

`-L    Like '-l', but also redirect the child's stdio to the slave.`

because of this error:

```
$ reptyr 30622

[-] Unable to open the tty in the child.
Unable to attach to pid 30622: Permission denied
```

And with -L

```
$ reptyr -L 30622
Opened a new pty: /dev/pts/4
```

Comment: How do we resume the suspended thread in the current terminal?