# Is it possible to transfer a running process to your terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, process, job-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I pause up a running process over ssh, disown it, associate it to a new screen shell and unpause it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-pause-up-a-running-process-over-ssh-disown-it-associate-it-to-a-new-s)

It is fairly easy to disown a process, or make it run without a tty, but is it possible to transfer to process to your own tty?

By “disown a process”, I’m talking about running a command using nohup, or by running the disown builtin.

Answer (score 2):

[`screen`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) is very handy for this. Launch screen, launch the process inside screen, detach from screen.  Then, `screen -DR` to resume.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [retty](http://pasky.or.cz/~pasky/dev/retty/) which finds the stdin, stdout and stderr of a process and attaches to them. However, you don't completely own the process like you did before so you can't send it signals.