# Move terminal emulator process from xorg to tty?

Tags: terminal, process, x11, console

Is it possible (and if so, how?) to move a process from a terminal emulator running in X to a different virtual terminal, so that I can restart the X server without killing the process running in the terminal emulator?

Similar questions:

- [Is it possible to transfer a running process to your terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9534/is-it-possible-to-transfer-a-running-process-to-your-terminal)
- [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell) (Edit: The question in this link has been incorrectly marked as a duplicate of my question. Note that the accepted answer to that question does not address my question. GNU `screen` currently can not incorporate processes that were invoked prior to invocation of `screen` and cannot take over ownership of the process to be moved to a terminal.

Comment: I've never seen any way of doing so. It would mean to redirect the stdin, stdout and stderr files, and assorted other state. Too hard, very little reason to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `screen`. This will allow you to detach your whole session and attach it again from some other terminal.

If you start it without `screen` your output is bound directly to that terminal. In this case you can use a tool like `reptyr` to transfer your process to another terminal. (Probably into a screen session. ;) )

Alternatives to `screen` are `tmux` and `dtach`.

Alternative to `reptyr` is `retty`.

Furthermore `neercs` seems to allow both.

Comment: You can attach an already running process to another terminal using [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr). @taz, search for `reptyr` here to find a lot of similar questions.

Comment: I was not aware of this. Thanks for the hint! - Answer updated.

Comment: I believe that `screen` and `tmux` are not options in this specific scenario because AFAIK I definitely need to change the process owner and controlling terminal of the process to be moved, so that it doesn't get killed when the X server shuts down. Also, I need this for a process that is already running in an X server that was not started using `screen` or any similar tools. At a glance, it looks like reptyr is exactly what I'm looking for.