# How to view the output of a running process in another bash session?

Tags: bash, process, io-redirection

I have left a script running on a remote machine from when I was locally working at it. I can connect over SSH to the machine as the same user and see the script running in `ps`.

```
$ ps aux | grep ipcheck
myuser  18386  0.0  0.0  18460  3476 pts/0    S+   Dec14   1:11 /bin/bash ./ipchecker.sh
```

It is simply outputting to stdout on a local session (I ran `./ipchecker.sh` form a local terminal window, no redirection, no use of `screen` etc).

Is there anyway from an SSH session I can view the output of this running command (without stopping it)?

So far the best I have found is to use `strace -p 18386` but I get hordes of text flying up the screen, its far too detailed. I can stop `strace` and then sift through the output and find the text bring printed to stdout but its very long and confusing, and obviously whilst it's stopped I might miss something. I would like to find a way to see the script output live as if I was working locally.

Can anyone improve on this? The obvious answer is to restart the script with redirection or in a `screen` session etc, this isn't a mission critical script so I could do that. Rather though, I see this as a fun learning exercise.

Comment: Is your process running in a virtual console or in a GUI/xterm like environment?

Comment: You can limit output of strace to one syscall: `strace -p 4232 -e write`

Comment: @jippie The machine is running a full GUI (Linux Mynt 13, XFCE desktop), I fired up a gnome-terminal.

Comment: There's at least a dozen of similar questions on this site. Look for [reptyr](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=reptyr) here to find a few of them (and an answer).

Answer (score 379):

You can access the output via the `proc` filesystem.

```
tail -f /proc/<pid>/fd/1
```

`1` = stdout, `2` = stderr

(or like @jmhostalet says: `cat /proc/<pid>/fd/1` if tail doesn't work)

Comment: It gives me: 'cannot open /proc/<my pid>/fd/1 for reading: No such device or address'.

Comment: yeah <my pid> should be *your process id*

Comment: This won't work if the output is going to a tty (or redirected to `/dev/null`) — it will only work if the output is redirected to a file.

Comment: The output of yum is not loading, coz it is downloading some file from a repo and the progress is not showing under the file 1

Comment: @mattdm facing same issue. is there any way to get stdout in that case?

Comment: are you sure it is the same process? Because if it exec's a wget or whatever then it's is a different process so another <pid>/fd/1

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 and it doesn't work.  In a session I do: `ping google.es` and in another one as root: `tail -f /proc/\`pgrep ping\`/fd/2` and nothing is shown.

Comment: you are right. Because fd 1 and 2 are symlinks to the /dev/pts device. You can't tail -f a pts device. Schedule your ping command as a cronjob and then do the same. tail -f will then work

Comment: workaround for tail -f of pts device: gdb -p <pid>, p dup2(open("/dev/pts/<number>", 1), 1), detach

Comment: `tail` doesn't work for me, I am using `sudo cat /proc/<pid>/fd/1` instead

Comment: somehow, neither of `tail cat more` works for me, but `strace -ewrite` does. I need `stdout` of a thread, `strace -ewrite -p 50287` shows it: `[pid 50287] write(1, "...", 97) = 97` - it does write to the `1` file descriptor. I see the output on the gnome terminal, but the utilities do not get it.

Answer (score 282):

If all you want to do is spy on the existing process, you can use `strace -p1234 -s9999 -e write` where 1234 is the process ID. (`-s9999` avoids having strings truncated to 32 characters, and `write` the system call that produces output.) If you want to view only data written on a particular file descriptor, you can use something like `strace -p1234 -e trace= -e write=3` to see only data written to file descriptor 3 (`-e trace=` prevents the system calls from being loged). That won't give you output that's already been produced.

If the output is scrolling by too fast, you can pipe it into a pager such as `less`, or send it to a file with `strace -o trace.log …`.

With many programs, you can divert subsequent output with a ptrace hack, either to your current terminal or to a new screen session. See [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell) and other linked threads.

Note that depending on how your system is set up, you may need to run all these `strace` commands as root even if the process is running under your user with no extra privileges. (If the process is running as a different user or is setuid or setgid, you will need to run `strace` as root.) [Most distributions only allow a process to trace its children](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Roadmap/KernelHardening#ptrace) (this provides a moderate security benefit — it prevents some direct malware injection, but doesn't prevent indirect injection by modifying files). This is controlled by the `kernel.yama.ptrace_scome` sysctl.

Comment: I don't suppose there's a way to narrow down the output to _just the standard output_?

Comment: Can you explain all the arguments?

Comment: There was a lot of backslashes and numbers in a lot of the output I was getting from nodejs; Any leads on what encoding they might be in? There was plenty of plain text too, which was all i needed.

Comment: @ThorSummoner If you see a backslash followed by three octal digits between double quotes in the strace output, that means a byte whose numeric value is given by the digits. You'll see that for non-ASCII characters.

Comment: "Can you explain all the arguments?"  @User: `man strace`

Comment: I have a php process running a websocket and some variables inside, but I can't stop it right now to 'echo/print_r'. Is there a way to capture those variables 'on the fly'?

Comment: @RafaelMoni A program to do what you're asking is called a debugger.

Comment: @Gilles well, damn. I didn't build the application. So, I guess I'll have to 'dissect' the application.

Comment: I came here looking for STDout and got a treasure trove of valuable debug data. Thanks!

Comment: I hope I'm not saying something stupid, but to only get stdout you can use:
strace -p1234 -s9999 -e write 2>&1|grep '^write(1'

Comment: @User https://explainshell.com/ allows you to paste a command and it'll explain the arguments, e.g. https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=strace+-p1234+-s9999+-e+write

Comment: worked for me with sudo

Comment: Thanks for this! See how to parse the output of `strace` in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528276/103904) below.

Comment: In case you're on a server which does not have `strace` by default, you can usually install it by running `yum install strace`.

Comment: To just get the current `ffplay` output, can `strace` be instructed to print one line and exit immediately? Currently it runs in a loop until `<CTRL>+C` is pressed. If relevant I will be calling `strace` from python and `ffplay` is also called from python but launched as a background task. Is a new question warranted in this case?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix `strace -p… … 2>&1 | head -n 1` will cause strace to exit when it can't write to the pipe anymore. I doubt that it would be useful to "get the current ffplay output" in this way, but there you are.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thank you. I agree `strace` is probably a silly way of solving the problem. I've actually started down a new path of parsing `ffplay` output redirected to temp file.

Answer (score 17):

In BSD, you can use [`watch`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?watch) which snoops a given tty, e.g.

```
watch /dev/pts/0
```

In Linux, it won't be possible if the process wasn't run under multiplexer before such as `screen` or `tmux`. See also: [Reptyr: Attach a Running Process to a New Terminal](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/)

It seems the only way is to debug the process (e.g. `strace`, `dtrace`/`dtruss`, [`gdb`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14731/21471), `lldb`, etc.).

Since you've used `strace`, to fetch any meaningful output, you need to filter by a qualifying expression (such as `file`), then parse the output. Here is example:

```
strace -e trace=write -s1000 -fp 18386 2>&1 | grep -o '".\+[^"]"'
```

What it does it prints write operation of the process (1000 length) specified by PID (use `pgrep` to find it by name), redirects standard error into output (to be filtered), and prints double-quoted string.

If you're dealing with binary output, you may parse escape sequences characters by using `read` (with `-r`) and `printf`  (with `%b`), e.g.

```
while read -r -t1 line; do printf "%b" $line; done
```

Check `help read` for more parameters (e.g. `-n` to print after certain amount of characters, rather than newline).

Here is more complete example:

```
strace -e trace=write -s1000 -fp 18386 2>&1 \
| grep --line-buffered -o '".\+[^"]"' \
| grep --line-buffered -o '[^"]\+[^"]' \
| while read -r line; do
  printf "%b" $line;
done
```

For examples using any process, please check: [How to parse strace in shell into plain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36557550/55075) at stackoverflow

Answer (score 9):

**Parsing the output of strace:**

I used the [top answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58601/103904) (with my process ID of 28223) ...

```
> sudo strace -p28223 -s9999 -e write
...
write(9, "Info\nI\nCare\nabout", 55) = 55
...
```

To determine that I care about `write(9`. (The 9 is used below, it's probably a file handle and might be different for your process.) Then I wrote a quick Ruby script to parse and display them.

Paste the following into `/usr/bin/parse_strace.rb`

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

num = ARGV[0]
STDIN.each { |line|
  if (line.match(/write\(#{ num },\s*"(.*?)"/)) then
    puts $1.split('\x').map { |s| s.to_i(16).chr }.join()
  end
}
```

Don't forget `chmod a+x /usr/bin/parse_strace.rb`

I invoke `strace -xx` (outputs hex, so the regex matches properly), piping (including STDERR) to my script with `9` as the first arg.

```
sudo sh -c 'strace -xx -p28223 -s9999 -e write 2>&1 | parse_strace.rb 9'
```

And, voila, it outputs the process's original STDOUT, newlines, color, and all!

[image: Attaching to process STDOUT]

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get stderr and stdout you can just run this:

```bsh
tail -f /proc/<pid>/fd/*
```

Answer (score 6):

You always can launch a process whith **nohup** and **&**

```
nohup rsync source_file dest_file &
```

Then, you'll can check the progress from any tty with:

```
tail -f nohup.out
```

This works fine to me.

Comment: This question I'd about how to view the output of an alert running process, not how to run a process in the background as your answer suggests

Comment: In fact, your :nohup mention enlighten me! Thanks!

Comment: interesting response, would u mind to elaborate it a bit more?

Answer (score 4):

I'd advise to make a named pipe (`mkfifo`) and then write to that file. Then, read from it. You can always do that with things like `tail`, to minimize output, etc. Whenever you clear the pipe (read from it), it gets cleared, so the output is not preserved.

The other option would be to write everything to a file (much like a logfile) and then analyze it an any time. This would be the preferred action, if you want to preserve all output.

Answer (score 4):

1. You might be able to peek at the remote screen using `ssh localhost 'DISPLAY=:0.0 xwd -root' | xwud -scale` where `localhost` is to be replaced by your remote server login credentials and `:0.0` with the display number of your GUI.
2. Use `x11vnc`, which is a VNC server for your on screen X-session.
3. When running on one of the 6 virtual consoles try `sudo setterm -dump 2 -file /dev/stdout`, where you replace `2` with the appropriate vc.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple to get the output would be capturing your output to a file and tailing that file.

IF DO:

```
./ipcheck
```

INSTEAD DO:

```
./ipcheck > [replacewithyourfilename]
```

This would create an output file where your script is located. Then from any other bash shell you can simply tail the file:

```
tail [replacewithyourfilename] -f
```

Comment: File redirection tends to use block-based buffering by default (see `setbuf(3)`) which might make a `tail` problematical.

Comment: Also this doesn't help with the question, which was about how to view the output of an already running process, not how to redirect stdout for a new process.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [catp](https://github.com/rapiz1/catp/) to do this.

It's basically `strace` with only tracee's output extracted.

Usage:
`catp $PID`

Answer (score 0):

In bash 1:

```
any_command_you_want > my_output.txt&
```

In bash 2:

```
cat my_output.txt
```

Comment: Pleas note that the OP said "Is there anyway from an SSH session I can view the output of this _running_ command (_without stopping it_)?". While your approach doesn't require stopping the command, it would not help to watch the output of a command that is already running (as in the OPs problem). Also, I would at least consider using `tail -f` instead of `cat` so that the output can be followed in near-realtime. You may want to look at the OPs comment to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361477/377345) which is basically the same as yours.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the commercial **LSF** from IBM as job scheduler, then you have also the option

bpeek
displays the stdout and stderr output of an unfinished job

```
bpeek [-f] [-q queue_name | -m host_name | -J job_name | job_ID |
"job_ID[index_list]"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using `strace`, `pgrep`, `grep` and `sed` filtering.

- create bash script

  ```bash
  nano ~/.local/bin/strace_cout
  ```
- copy paste

  ```bash
  #/usr/bin/bash
  PID_CUR=$(pgrep $1)
  STREAM=1 # 1 = stdout 2 = stderr
  strace -p$PID_CUR -s9999 -e write 2>&1 \
   | grep --line-buffered -E "^write\($STREAM," \
   | sed -u -e 's/^[^"]*"//' | sed 's/\\n"[^"]*$//'
  ```
- Example use:

  ```bash
  ./strace_cout name_of_process
  ```