# How to switch to other users's process?

Tags: process

A user has started a Java program and is currently running.

As root, I can see it through `ps -A`.

How can I bring this process to foreground?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is: A process can only be brought to the foreground in the terminal it was started in. Its stdin, stdout and stderr are linked to that window and they can't be changed from the outside i.e. from another process.

The long answer is: There are some options to see some of its output, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58550/how-to-view-the-output-of-a-running-process-in-another-bash-session)

Comment: Is there a way to write into its stdin in terminal?

Comment: You can send characters using `echo 'abcd' > /proc/PID/fd/0`, but they are likely not executed. Another option is to use `reptyr -s PID`. (I couldn't get it to work though). In both cases `PID` is the process id of the process you are trying to attach to.