# How to redirect a running process output when the output device is deleted

Tags: shell, curl

I was trying to inspect a *disowned* `curl` process, which was started in an earlier login. I can see that it (PID 17193) is still running:

```
$ ps aux | grep curl
17193 jack 7700 3692 S      1:00 20:48  curl https://examples.com/file.ext -O
18124 jack 3576  876 S      0:00 21:18  grep curl
```

And I was trying to see how far the downloading is going, but the output of it has been deleted:

```
$ ls -l /proc/17193/fd
total 0
lrwx------    1 jack users           64 May 19 20:50 0 -> /dev/pts/1 (deleted)
lrwx------    1 jack users           64 May 19 20:50 1 -> /dev/pts/1 (deleted)
lrwx------    1 jack users           64 May 19 20:50 2 -> /dev/pts/1 (deleted)
lrwx------    1 jack users           64 May 19 20:50 3 -> socket:[2343571]
l-wx------    1 jack users           64 May 19 20:50 4 -> /dir/file.ext
```

What I should do to see the output? Thanks!

Comment: After reading [@JdeBP accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444861/453746), I am not sure anymore :) However, [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/58601/453746) in another post shows a way to do that with `sudo strace -p17193 -s9999 -e write` (tested). Although your process must be death by now, it may help others reaching out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible without a debugger.

Your program's standard output and standard error are going to the slave side of a pseudo-terminal whose master side has been closed.  There is no way, short of extreme measures such as debugging the process and intercepting system calls, to access its output.

These are the semantics of terminals.

If you hangup the terminal session (i.e. hangup a real terminal's serial device, exit a login session on a kernel virtual terminal device, hangup the master side of a pseudo-terminal as used by SSH/user-space virtual terminals/TELNET/rlogin/X11 terminal emulators) the open file descriptors for processes that still reference that terminal are *intended* not to cause I/O nor be connected to anything any more.  It is the Unix approach to combatting trojan horse programs that used to hang on to open file descriptors to terminal devices and use them to present fake login prompts to the next user of the terminal.

This has long since begotten programs such as `tmux`, GNU Screen, mosh, or [`console-terminal-emulator`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/console-terminal-emulator.html) which sit holding the master side of a pseudo-terminal open, emulate a terminal's display and input, and allow disconnectable and reconnectable client/realizer processes (i.e. the "client" parts of `tmux` and GNU Screen; mosh clients; or [`console-fb-realizer`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/console-fb-realizer.html), [`console-termio-realizer`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/console-termio-realizer.html), or some other such) to render that onto real devices.

So use `tmux`, GNU Screen, mosh, a nosh toolset's user-space virtual terminal, or some other such system if you want reconnectability.

## Further reading

- [pty](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?pty). *NetBSD Kernel Interfaces Manual*.  2013-11-13.
- [`revoke`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=revoke&sektion=2).  *FreeBSD System Calls Manual*.  2016-01-25.
- [`vhangup`](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/manpages-dev/vhangup.2.en.html).  *Linux Programmer's Manual*.  Debian Manual pages.  2016-03-15.
- [Daniel J. Bernstein on TTYs in Unix](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/bernstein-on-ttys/).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard.  [User-space virtual terminals](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/user-virtual-terminals.html).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that! I never thought the consideration behind this design was for security and fraud-proof purposes! That's so so thoughtful and refreshing! I did see answers on similar questions indicating that debuggers such as `gdb` would work. I would love to try these methods. It's just that the thing is the BusyBox I am working with does not have `gdb` or `tmux`. And the device is running on an ARM CPU, which makes the situation even more complex...

Answer (score 2):

Seeing is easy:

```
cat /proc/17193/fd/1 ; tail -n 0 -f /proc/17193/fd/1
```

Real redirection is complicated. You could attach a debugger to the running process, close the fd and open it for a new file. But with active networking I guess this has to be done quickly in order to avoid connections being broken.

Comment: Does that actually work? If you re-open a `/dev/pts/` device for reading like that, do the reads give you the stuff written to the terminal (by an application), or the stuff coming from the terminal (typed by the user)?

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried this method, but got three lines of errors: 1. `cat: can't open '/proc/19927/fd/1': Input/output error`; 2. `tail: can't open '/proc/19927/fd/1': Input/output error`; 3. `tail: no files`. (**19927** is the PID of `curl` in this time).

Comment: @ilkkachu I have to admit that I did not notice that those were ptys. How do you delete a pty? If the controlling terminal of a process disappears then the kernel kills the process... But it probably just sends `SIGHUP` which may be ignored.

Comment: @HaukeLaging The system I am using is running BusyBox. And the active ssh session is `pty/0` according to `$ who`.

Answer (score 2):

As JdeBP says, this is impossible without attaching as a debugger. Luckily, there exist programs to do exactly that in a fully-automated way. [Reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) is one such program. Just run `reptyr 17193`, and it will be reconnected to your terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation! I will try this as soon as I get back to the device!