# Using Tail on a process causes character input delay & disruption

Tags: process, tail, delay

I was referring to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58550/399271) question to see if it is possible to spy on another running process' stdout. One answer suggests using `tail -f /proc/<PID>/fd/1` to do so. So I opened two terminal sessions to try it. In the first terminal, I echoed the PID using `echo $$`. In the second terminal, I executed the tail command (without root privileges). I then noticed that there is significant hangup in the first terminal's IO (typing into the shell was disrupted and there was significant key delay). Why does this happen?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I'm more interested in knowing why typing is disrupted in the other terminal, not why the tail command didn't work as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 1):

Running `strace tail -f /proc/<PID>/fd/1` provides a clue.

The last line of the output will show that the `tail` command is waiting to read from the process.

> read(3,

As you type into the original process, some of the characters will show up in that process and some will show up in the output of `strace` command. For example, typing "1234" in the original process may show 24 in the original process and the following lines in the `strace` output:

> read(3, "1", 8192)                      = 1
>   read(3, "3", 8192)                      = 1

Although not apparent when running `tail` without `strace`, the `tail` command competes with the original process for access to what is typed.