# How to view the output of a running process in another bash session on mac?

Tags: process, macintosh, stdout, stderr

I have a process running and I would like to know what it prints to stdout and stderr. On linux I would do

```
tail -f /proc/<pid>/fd/1
```

[See here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58550/how-to-view-the-output-of-a-running-process-in-another-bash-session)

How do I do this on macOS?

Comment: Don't think you can. You could use screen/tmux but this would only works if you run one of them first.

Comment: That really is a shame. Thank you very much for the answer, though

Comment: It's not even possible on linux.  Note this comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58550/how-to-view-the-output-of-a-running-process-in-another-bash-session#comment640573_308666. When you start the process you must output to a file, then you *can* `tail -f <the file>`.

Comment: +1 use `screen` to run the process and `screen -x` to also connect to the screen or just reconnect to it normally.