# How can I move a process into the background and also silence its output?

Tags: job-control

Say I start a process in the terminal and it sends output to standard error while it runs. I want to move the process into the background and also silence it at the same time.

Is there a way to do this without stopping the process and starting it again using `&` and `> /dev/null 2>&1` ? I'm wondering if there is some command that performs `bg`  and can change the output descriptors of the target process too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Too late. After a *process* is started, shell has no more control on *process* file descriptors so you can not *silence* it by a shell command.

You can only try to *kill* a `SIGHUP` to the process. **If your process handles it correctly**, It should detach from *controlling tty*. Unluckily, many software do not handle it correctly and simply die.

Comment: can't you do CTRL+Z to put the process in background?   it doesn't silence the process, and if you log out, i think it kills the process too.

Comment: @RoyRico, *killing* a `SIGSTOP` to a process (or as you say *doing CTRL+Z*) does not silence a process. It stops a process!

Answer (score 5):

The process that is run from a terminal has its stdin, stdout and stderr bound to the terminal and you cannot do anything about it without re-gaining control over that terminal... Normally. But there are some tricky tools that actually let you do it.  Have a look at [this example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17648/what-happens-to-the-output-of-a-process-that-has-been-disowned-and-lost-its-termi/20092#20092). And other programs like `retty` mentioned there.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with andcoz that it is too late to silence the output.

Assuming the process is running in the foreground, use `Ctrl-Z` to suspend the process.  Doing so will report the job number and the process ID.  You can go ahead and move the process to the background using `bg %1` (for job #1).  Although this moves the process to the background, it doesn't silence the output.  To silence the output you can use `gdb` to redirect all output to `/dev/null`.

This has been very nicely described previously at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin/593764#593764.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another command-line tool is `detach`. The latest version supports writing pidfiles, using files for stdin, stdout and stderr, and running in the foreground. (The website of `detach` also discusses similar tools.)

http://inglorion.net/software/detach/