# Where do background jobs go?

Tags: shell, job-control, jobs, background-process

From gnome-terminal I know the ability to suspend a job with C-z, and then send it to the background. When I close the terminal the process does not end. Where is the job being managed from, or is it lost?

Comment: This looks almost as a duplicate of a question [I've asked](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17648/what-happens-to-the-output-of-a-process-that-has-been-disowned-and-lost-its-term), though expressed differently. Have a look for some insightful answers.

Comment: Why do you think it does not end?  When you close the terminal, a SIGHUP signal is sent to all processes attached to it, which normally kills them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your background job continues executing until someone tells it to stop by sending it a signal. There are several ways it might die:

- When the terminal goes away for any reason, it sends a [HUP signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP) (“hangup”, as in modem hangup) to the shell running inside it (more precisely, to the [controlling process](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_113)) and to the process in the [foreground process group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html#tag_11_01_02). A program running in the background is thus not affected, but…
- When the shell receives that HUP signal, it propagates it to the background jobs. So if the background process is not ignoring the signal, it dies at this point.
- If the program tries to read or write from the terminal after it's gone away, 
  the read or write will fail with an input/output error (EIO). The program may then decide to exit.
- You (or your system administrator), of course, may decide to kill the program at any time.

If your concern is to keep the program running, then:

- If the program may interact with the terminal, use [Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [Tmux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) to run the program in a virtual terminal that you can disconnect from and reconnect to at will.
- If the program just needs to keep running and is not interactive, start it with the `nohup` command (`nohup myprogram --option somearg`), which ensures that the shell won't send it a SIGHUP, redirects standard input to `/dev/null` and redirects standard output and standard error to a file called `nohup.out`.
- If you've already started the program and don't want it to die when you close your terminal, run the `disown` built-in, if your shell has one. If it doesn't, you can avoid the shell's propagation of SIGHUP by killing the shell with extreme prejudice (`kill -KILL $$` from that shell, which bypasses any exit trigger that the indicated process has).
- If you've already started the program and would like to reattach it to another terminal, there are ways, but they're not 100% reliable. See [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-it-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell) and linked questions.

Answer (score 2):

The job can be further controlled by sending appropriate signals (using `kill` command for example).

You may try this:

- run some long running command (`yes` for example, as from its output we can see, that the process is running)
- press `Ctrl + Z`
- determine process pid: `pgrep yes`
- resume process (equivalent to `bg` or `fg`) using: `kill -CONT <PID>`, where  `<PID>` is the proces id determined in previous step

Answer (score 0):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> you don't send the process to the background, you set it to sleep. You can wake it up with the `fg` command  (foreground). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> sends the `SIGSTOP` (19) signal to the process.

You can prove this:

- Open two terminals; in one of them type this command `yes running`, it will print 'running''running''running' repeatedly on the terminal
- Stop the process with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> and look for its PID with the `ps` command.
- Type this in the second terminal: `kill -19 the_previous_PID`, you'll see it produce the same effect for the 'yes' process.

If you type `kill -l` you'll see a list of all the signals you can use.