# How do I attach a terminal to a detached process?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal, process

I have detached a process from my terminal, like this:

```
$ process &
```

That terminal is now long closed, but `process` is still running, and I want to send some commands to that process's stdin. Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disown it a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-it-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)

Comment: Search for `retty`, `neercs`, etc. and see also http://serverfault.com/questions/24425, http://serverfault.com/questions/115998

Comment: Easiest way (if you are still in same terminal) is to run `jobs` (to see, if process is still running) and if yes, use `fg` to being it to foreground. After that, you can start sending commands and you will also receive stdout data. PS: "sending it to background again" can be done using `CTRL+Z` (suspend) and than running `bg` (run last job in background). See some tutorials for this topic to learn more.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Yes, it is. First, create a pipe:
`mkfifo /tmp/fifo`.
 Use gdb to attach to the process:
`gdb -p PID`

Then close stdin: `call close (0)`; and open it again: `call open ("/tmp/fifo", 0600)`

Finally, write away (from a different terminal, as gdb will probably hang):

`echo blah > /tmp/fifo`

Comment: Very impressive!

Comment: Can I do something similar to redirect process stdout to a file?

Comment: @rustyx: Untested, but this should work: create a file rather than a pipe, `touch /tmp/thefile`. Stdout is 1, so `call close (1)`; also, use the correct permissions for writing: `call open ("/tmp/thefile", 0400)`. The `echo…` is, of course, not needed.

Comment: This is great! I'm using this to send "y" or "n" responses to certain processes that have been completely detached.  The detached process has its stdout to a separate window.  When I do this trick however, I can see that it does not "receive" the 'y' or 'n' as soon as I echo it, I must quit gdb and detach it and then it receives all of the echos accordingly, so is there a way to perform this without needing to quit gdb before the process receives the input from the fifo?

Comment: unfortunately it just seem hung on `call open("/tmp/fifo", 0600)`. any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: i think you should use `continue` command of gdb to continue its process after doing the commands given to it

Comment: is this still valid? unfortunately does not work for me (ubuntu 18)

Comment: I believe this should be `call open ("/tmp/fifo", 0)` (Open for reading.) 0600 would be appropriate for a third argument to `open` if the second argument has the O_CREAT (0100) flag. Using 0600 as a second argument, it's O_RDONLY|O_EXCL|O_NOCTTY on Linux, which seems to be OK, but O_EXCL without O_CREAT is undefined (unless the file in a block device).

Answer (score 58):

When original terminal is no longer accessible...

`reptyr` might be what you want, see https://serverfault.com/a/284795/187998

Quote from there:

> Have a look at [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr), which does exactly that.  The github page has all the information.

> ### reptyr - A tool for "re-ptying" programs.
>
> reptyr is a utility for taking an
> existing running program and attaching
> it to a new terminal. Started a
> long-running process over ssh, but
> have to leave and don't want to
> interrupt it? Just start a screen, use
> reptyr to grab it, and then kill the
> ssh session and head on home.
>
> ### USAGE
>
> reptyr PID
>
> "reptyr PID" will grab the process
> with id PID and attach it to your
> current terminal.
>
> After attaching, the process will take
> input from and write output to the new
> terminal, including ^C and ^Z.
> (Unfortunately, if you background it,
> you will still have to run "bg" or
> "fg" in the old terminal. This is
> likely impossible to fix in a
> reasonable way without patching your
> shell.)

Edit claims that "`reptyr` cannot grab a process which has subprocesses. Or the subprocess (reptyr version 0.6.2)." Limited support does exist [Issue](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr/issues/24), [Issue](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr/issues/84)

Comment: If it's not installed, try `sudo yum install -y reptyr`.  This worked great for me to take over a `vi` editing session I lost when my SSH connection dropped (just had to press `^L` after taking it back over to see all my changes and continue editing).

Comment: I did not have this installed, and could not use the package manager because the process I was disconnected from was dpkg. I downloaded the deb (https://pkgs.org/download/reptyr), did a `dpkg-deb --extract reptyr_0.6.2-1.2_amd64.deb reptyr && reptyr/usr/bin/reptyr $PID_OF_WANTED_PROCESS`

Comment: Did essentially the same as @miigotu: downloaded (what I hoped was) the right package from https://pkgs.org/download/reptyr and extracted `reptyr`... was able to save a file from a detached VI session.

Comment: In my scenario, I was able to use the newer `-T` argument like `reptyr -T <pid>` to  reconnect (I was running as root already btw)

Comment: @miigotu : Thank you for this!!  Just had to perform the same emergency maneuver due to `nouveau` driver locking up the display on a system running `apt-get` + `dpkg-reconfigure` on thousands of packages during an upgrade.  Very inopportune time for `nouveau` kernel module to crash, but now I can  SSH in and use `reptyr` to make sure the upgrade is complete before rebooting the system.

Answer (score 14):

I am quite sure you can not.

Check using `ps x`. If a process has a `?` as *controlling tty*, you can not send input to it any more.

```
9942 ?        S      0:00 tail -F /var/log/messages
9947 pts/1    S      0:00 tail -F /var/log/messages
```

In this example, you can send input to `9947` doing something like `echo "test" > /dev/pts/1`. The other process (`9942`) is not reachable.

Next time, you could use [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) to avoid this situation.

Comment: Or [`dtach`](http://dtach.sourceforge.net/) if you not need a whole `screen`.

Comment: There is no way in the standards (POSIX, SUS), but on many (most?) systems it *is* possible using the mechanisms that debuggers use. See [Ansgar's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31830/3270). With `root` you could even do this to other user's processes.

Comment: Doing `echo "test" > /dev/pts/1` won't send input to process `9947` - it will output the word "test" on that process's terminal.

Answer (score 8):

Just ending the command line with `&` will not completely detach the process, it will just run it in the background. (With `zsh` you can use `&!` to actually detach it, otherwise you have do `disown` it later).

When a process runs in the background, it won't receive input from its controlling terminal anymore. But you can send it back into the foreground with `fg` and then it will read input again.

Otherwise, it's not possible to externally change its filedescriptors (including stdin) or to reattach a lost controlling terminal… unless you use debugging tools (see [Ansgar's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31830/9426), or have a look at the `retty` command).

Comment: And there is a related question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17648/9426

Comment: @Rogach stated "That terminal is now long closed".

Comment: @andcoz: Yes but he's been lucky that the program has not been SIGHUPed. I was suggesting a safer method.

Comment: here, disown only really works if I first redirect stdout like with `>>/dev/stderr`, otherwise, when I close the terminal, the "disowned" process will end too.. I never really understood this tho..

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT** : As Stephane Gimenez said, it's not that simple. It's only allowing you to print to a different terminal.

You can try to write to this process using */proc*. It should be located in */proc/**pid**/fd/0*, so a simple :

```
echo "hello" > /proc/PID/fd/0
```

should do it. I have not tried it, but it should work, as long as this process still has a valid *stdin* file descriptor. You can check it with `ls -l` on */proc/**pid**/fd/*.

- if it's a link to /dev/null => it's closed
- if it's a link to /dev/pts/X or a socket => it's open

See [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) for more details about how to keep processes running.

Comment: It's not that simple. For example, If stdin is linked to a terminal, `echo`ing something to the terminal device will just print what you wrote on the terminal, it will not be transmitted to the process.