# Bring process to 'foreground'?

Tags: ssh, solaris, ps

I am using an SSH client to connect to a Solaris server.  I had a process running but my connection disconnected.  I reconnected and can see the process running when I do `ps -al`.  How can I bring this process to the 'foreground'?  I want to see its output.

Comment: Wow your question so good. But i would like to know how you started job ?

Comment: I started job by doing `perl some_script.pl`.

Comment: Not sure it works on Solaris, but the question was answered here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-to-attach-terminal-to-detached-process

Answer (score 4):

You can immediately re-activate your most recent **backgrounded** task by typing:

```
fg
```

If you have multiple backgrounded tasks, you can see the available jobs by typing:

```
jobs
```

You can then bring any of the tasks to the foreground by using the index in the first column with a percentage sign:

```
fg %
```

for example:

output of `jobs` command shows the process job number

```
[1]+  Stopped                 ssh username@some_host
[2]   Stopped                 ssh username@another_host
```

Bring any of the tasks to the foreground by using the index:

```
fg%2
```

Comment: How do you send a task to the background?

Comment: @CJ7 - Using 'bg &' command

Comment: This only works for processes started from the current shell, attached to the same TTY. The OP's question implies that he disconnected and reconnected from the host. The shell bg/fg commands probably won't be sufficient in this case.