# How to pipe commands to a process running in the background?

Tags: process, pipe, input

This is my loop program, running in the background and waiting for a command.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char buffer[256];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    while(true){
     fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
     buffer[255] = 0;
     if(buffer[0] != '\0'){
        cout << buffer;
        buffer[0] = '\0';
     } 
    }
 return 0;
}
```

I ran it with:

```
myLoop &
```

Now, how can I pipe a command to this process?

Comment: You don't.  If you actually run the program the way you say you did you'll note the shell saying something like `[1]+  Stopped`.  That's because your program has received a `SIGTTIN` signal, for trying to read from the terminal while running in background.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess that is impossible with a "real" pipeline.

Instead you can use a FIFO (named pipe, see `man mkfifo`) or (more elegant but more complicated) a Unix socket (AF_UNIX).

```
./background-proc </path/to/fifo &
cat >/path/to/fifo
# typing commands into cat
```

I am not a developer so my only relation to sockets is `socat`. But that may help as a start.

You need a "server" which communicates with your program. Such a pipeline would be started in the background:

```
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/sockettest,fork STDOUT | sed 's/./&_/g'
```

The `sed` is just for testing.

Then you start one or more

```
socat STDIN UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/sockettest
```

If you have a program which generates the commands for your background program then you would use a pipeline here, too:

```
cmd_prog | socat STDIN UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/sockettest
```

The advantage in comparison with a FIFO is that (with the option `fork` on the server side) you can disconnect and reconnect the client. Using a FIFO you would need tricks for keeping the receiving side running:

```
while true; do cat /path/to/fifo; done | background_prog
```

Comment: Thank you, i think the best way is fifo. can you refer me to a good example of Unix socket (AF_UNIX)?

Comment: @mamrezo see edit

Answer (score 12):

If you wanted to start the command in background and have a file descriptor to send data to it via a pipe.

With `zsh` or `bash`, you could use a redirection to a process substitution.

```
exec 3> >(cmd)
```

And then send output with:

```
echo something >&3
```

And tell end-of-file with `exec 3>&-`.

Sill with `zsh` and `bash`, you can also do:

```
{ coproc cmd >&3 3>&-; } >&3
```

That is start `cmd` as a co-process, which starts the process with two pipes, one for input, one for output, but here as we only want the one for input, we restore `cmd`'s stdout to that of the rest of the shell.

To send output:

```
echo something >&p # with zsh
echo something >&"${COPROC[1]}" # with bash
```

With `yash`, you can use *process redirection*:

```
exec 3>(cmd)
```

With any Bourne-like shell, you can always do:

```
{ {
  echo something >&3
  echo whatever
  ...
} 3>&1 >&4 4>&- | cmd; } 4>&1
```

That's not exactly the same as starting `cmd` in background and run commands that send their output to `cmd` in that those commands run in a subshell and, for interactive shells, `cmd` is also in the foreground (is affected by Ctrl+C for instance), but apart from that, it's mostly functionally equivalent.

Comment: This one is the best answer because it avoids the mkfifo hassles.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you can't change what files a process has open and where they point to from outside that process after the process has been started. There are exceptions in the form of debugging interfaces and tools like [repty](https://serverfault.com/questions/55880/moving-an-already-running-process-to-screen/284795#284795) that can do this in a limited fashion.

When you started your program with

```
myLoop &
```

its standard input was connected to your terminal (because you didn't redirect it anywhere else) and that's not going to change to a pipe.

See also [How to attach terminal to detached process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-to-attach-terminal-to-detached-process)

Comment: Note that POSIX shells redirect the stdin of asynchronous jobs to /dev/null when non-interactive.