# How to exit nano from a different terminal?

Tags: bash, process, raspbian, nano

I was ssh'ing into a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, editing a file with nano, when I lost my internet connection (by leaving the WiFi zone). After reconnecting an hour later, I found that the pi had kicked me out, but after logging back in, I saw that it did not stop the task. When I reopened nano, it told me that the file was being edited by the previous nano process, and it gave me the PID. I made substantial changes to the file and forgot to save, but presumably the changes are still there.

How can I tell nano to save & quit (^O -> Enter -> ^X) or reopen the task in a new shell, from outside the original process?

Comment: It's unlikely you'll be able to reattach to that session, or send it anything meaningful. If nano 'knows' that the file is open, there's a good chance that the temporary save has been written somewhere and this serverfault answer may be how you are required to resolve this: https://serverfault.com/questions/453703/can-i-recover-a-nano-process-from-a-previous-terminal

Comment: One of nano’s online man pages indicates it will write buffers out to files named nano.save if it receives a HUP or TERM signal. Test on an innocent file first!

Comment: maybe this link will help you : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-to-attach-terminal-to-detached-process?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I see a <myfile.py.save> file in my directory, thanks @JeffSchaller, would you like to write an answer?

Comment: I would, but cannot right now. Please feel free to do so yourself.

Comment: And next you'll get used to starting a screen session before doing any serious remote editing :)

Comment: Yeah, before I asked this question, I didn't even know what that is. However, now that I'm trying to run it, bash tells me it has no idea what `screen` means.

Comment: tmux is a functional alternative to screen

Comment: tmux also not found @JeffSchaller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, @JeffSchaller noted that a terminated nano process saves the unwritten file in `file_path.extension.save`.

If it is there, which it was for me, it is a simple matter of `mv`ing the file into its original name.