# Trying to open and log output of a new gnome-terminal window

Tags: debian, terminal

I am trying to write a short script that opens a new terminal window, executes a variable that starts a game server, and logs the output of that new window.

The server sends a huge amount of spam in the console that is entirely useless, so I also wanted to append -q so the window is hidden.

My end goal is to look through the log for "Connected to Steam servers" using grep and report it in the main console. Currently I have the following:

```
$server="$game_path/server_executable"
gnome-terminal -- $server
```

Anything I add to gnome-terminal breaks the code. I have tried using  `gnome-terminal -- "$server 2>&1 | tee server.log"`
to the gnome-terminal line but it breaks. I've also tried `gnome-terminal -- "@server >> server.log"` but that fails too. I can't figure out the answer to get the new shell running the server command *and* exporting the output to a log file.

Running on Debian 12.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is to use something like `screen` or `tmux` so that the service continues to run if you close the terminal window. However, that's not what you've asked...

> ```
> gnome-terminal -- "$server 2>&1 | tee server.log"
> ```

This is nearly right. Let's check the documentation (`man gnome-terminal`)

> ```
> gnome-terminal [OPTION…] [-- PROGRAM [ARG…]]
> ```

And, somewhat confusingly,

> **`--command, -e=COMMAND`** Split the argument to this option into a program and arguments in the same way a shell would, and execute the resulting command-line inside the terminal.
> This option is deprecated. Instead, use `--` to terminate the options, and put the program and arguments to execute after it: for example, instead of `gnome-terminal -e "python3 -q"`, prefer to use `gnome-terminal -- python3 -q`.

All well so far. But,

> Note that the `COMMAND` is not run via a shell: it is split into words and executed as a program. If shell syntax is required, use the form `gnome-terminal -- sh -c '...'`

This last paragraph is the key: you cannot use `|` and `>` directly with `gnome-terminal`; you have to invoke a shell to interpret it:

```
$server="$game_path/server_executable"
gnome-terminal -- sh -c "$server 2>&1 | tee server.log"
```

Personally I'd prefer to use `screen`, with or without `gnome-terminal`:

```
gnome-terminal -- screen sh -c 'game_path/server_executable 2>&1 | tee server.log'
```

Or if you don't really want the `gnome-terminal` part and it was just a means to starting your game server,

```
screen -md sh -c 'game_path/server_executable 2>&1 | tee server.log'
```

Lots of help [here on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnu-screen) for manipulating `screen` sessions, for example [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457165/100397) to [Pause a process and bring it back to foreground in a separate screen in Ubuntu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/457153/100397)