# Shell scripts: How to copy past outputs of terminal emulator?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, terminal, terminal-emulator

I want to make a shell script which copies the past outputs of the GUI terminal emulator (for example, last 20 lines).
The motivation is as following:

When I execute a procedure which requires long time (for example, downloading a very large file, or converting a very large movie file), I sometimes remember another job, and I have to leave the room. In such a case, I press ctrl+z to stop the procedure. And I type

```
fg; echo $? >> log.txt; date >> log.txt; systemctl poweroff
```

then I leave the room.

This way works and is not bad. But it has a disadvantage that I cannot read the outputs of the procedure. I can know only the status ($?). So I want to copy last 20 or 40 lines and save them in log file.

Comment: If you do this a lot, you'd be better off getting into the habit of redirecting the output to a file (or using `tee` to redirect to a file AND to stdout).   Alternatively, depending on which window manager you use, you could use a screenshotting tool - most allow you to screenshot a particular window rather than the entire screen.  e.g. `xfce4-screenshooter`'s `-w` option takes a shot of the currently active window (if necessary, you could use wmctrl or similar to select which window is active).   Finally `tmux` has a `save-buffer` option to save the current buffer to a file.

Comment: and one more option: just don't bother powering it off at all - is that essential just because you've left the room?  You could just lock the screen or suspend/hibernate the machine instead of powering it off.

Comment: Possibly relevant [How do I attach a terminal to a detached process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31824/100397) and [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4034/100397)

Comment: @cas Thank you for your comment. Screenshot is easy and useful. And you are right, power off is not essential. I want to stop electricity, so hibernation seems to be better for my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your command with `nohup`, `screen` or `tmux` in the first place. Of course this won't help if you already started your process.

If that is the case, you can capture output of your command using `strace`:

```bsh
strace -p<PID> -s9999 -e write  2>&1 | grep -o '".\+[^"]"'
```

(replace `<PID>` with the `PID` of your process)

---

If `strace` cannot attach to the process, you might need to run as `root` / with `sudo` or [change your ptrace settings](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/security/Yama.txt) to `0` (and be aware of the security implications of it!):

```bsh
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

You can redirect that output to a file then.

---

There are other options, e.g. `gdb` or `reredirect`. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin).

Comment: I just tested in Ubuntu, and it says it cannot attach. "*If your uid matches the uid of the target process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try again as the root user.*" With `sudo` it works fine. That file has content `1` for me.

Comment: added information. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. strace can save all the outputs, so it will help me a lot. I have used strace sereral times, but I couldn't think of using strace for such a purpose.