# controlling a process from a different session

Tags: ssh, process

So, I ssh into my remote computer and launch a process... time passes... my ssh session breaks. I log in again, and of course, I don't have access to the original process now. I can see it still if I `ps -ax` but I can't do nothing about it other than kill it. Which, sometimes, may not be advisable, such as when the original process is, say, vacuuming a sqlite3 database.

So, can I get control of that process from a previous broken ssh session? If yes, how?

Comment: Try running all your ssh processes inside a GNU `screen` session, which you can detach and re-attach at will. `screen` to start a session, `C-a d` to detach it, `screen -d -r` to detach and reattach.

Comment: ...or tmux. See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-it-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell

Comment: awesome... thanks. Will have to learn the ins and outs of screen, but seems like it will be worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at */proc/PID/fd/* there you can see what happend to your old stdin and stdout. Sometimes you can use `echo` to send something to the stdin device of that process.

If you just want to prevent commands from being killed after your session breaks you can start them with `nohup`.

But the best answers to your question are possibly the comments about **screen** resp. **tmux**.