# Enter process running in background/bring to foreground

Tags: process, java, background-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disown it a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-it-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)

I started a java client using nohup to get it to run in the background (needed to log out of ssh). Now how can I enter it? (need to get it to save its progress)

I ran ps -x and its pid is 5220

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check the progress of your program, just check a file called *nohup.out*, by:

```
tail -f nohup.out
```

All stdout of your program will be written to this file.

Also, have a look at this [blog](http://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/).