# Is there any way to get control over a terminal by ssh with no (screen)

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disown it a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-it-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)

Let's say I'm install applications directly on to a Linux box.

May I go to another machine and connect (via SSH) and take control of the main terminal's screen? Could I make it so that the main terminal would be switched off and show a login prompt?

I could use `screen` but I haven't install it yet.

Comment: As far as i know you cannot do that without screen.

I have done a lot of research about that same problem i have had, but no joy.

Comment: Yes, the same to me. That's why I'm asking. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid but why don't you install screen and use it?

Comment: you are not stupid. Next time I will install screen and use it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this. The commands running on that TTY read and write from a specific TTY device (`/dev/ttyX`). There is no way to redirect output from that TTY device to your current TTY, and no way to send output from your current TTY device to that one.

In short, once youre on a TTY, you can not change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can SSH into the box, background the said task, kill the TTY on the host machine, and kill the user (`kill -u`) which should do about what you're wanting.

Comment: COOL! Will test!