# How can I manage jobs after I disconnect from my tty/ssh session?

Tags: ubuntu, process, background-process, process-management, jobs

If I `ssh` to a box and start a task that will take some time to complete I usually press `control+z` to pause the process, and then immediately type `bg 1` to put run it in the background.

I can then type `jobs` and see it running.

If I disconnect (type `exit`, press `control+d`, etc) and then log back in, I can no longer type `jobs` to see it running - it won't show anything.

I know I can type something like

```
ps -u `whoami`
```

to see what items are running, but I'm not sure if I can pause them any longer. I know I can kill them, but is there a way to pause them or can I somehow get them to show back up in the `jobs` list?

*Linux-fu tips regarding jobs and process management are also welcome and will be upvoted.*

Comment: Run a tmux session on the remote box... It makes <strike>job control</strike> _everything_ easier.

Comment: Run all long-timed processes inside [Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [Tmux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux). If you've already started a process outside one of these, see [How can I disown it a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4034) but that doesn't always work (sometimes it'll crash your program), so it's best to plan ahead. Systematically using Screen or Tmux on remote connections is a good habit to get into.

Comment: thank you both. i've never heard of those but i will be trying to get started with them this week. I'm going to google for tutorials and read the man pages unless you guys have some specific links that would be helpful for a Screen/Tmux noob. guess these would be better than just having multiple tabs in the terminal program :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `kill -STOP pid` to pause a job and `kill -CONT pid` to resume it.  You get the proper pid from the ps command you already know.