# any way to un-disown / re-attach an interactive process to the tty?

Tags: bash, terminal, tty, jobs, background-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)

In `bash` is there an opposite of `disown`, that is, to re-attach a process I've accidentally disowned aiming for another backgrounded job?

I suspended **ssh** to another host, launched **xload &**, and meant to disown *xload* not my ssh session.

```
master@im~/dev Thu Mar 08,15:27:18$ (4350) ^Z [suspend ssh]
[2]+  Stopped                 ssh -e ^] -o StrictHostKeyChecking=false -XCg master@5.39.81.187

master@quant~ Thu Mar 08,15:27:18$ (4834) [ $(pidof xload) ] || xload -display :99 -update 5 -geometry 1100x50 & disown
[3] 11943
bash: warning: deleting stopped job 2 with process group 17683
```

*Oops!*

```
master@quant~ Thu Mar 08,15:28:35$ (4826) jb
[3]- 11943 Running                 xload -display :99 -update 5 -geometry 1100x50 &
```