# attach to tty running a process

Tags: gnu-screen, java, tty

I have a systemd service file that runs a java program in another tty

```
[Unit]
Description=java program
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -cp "/home/user/someclass.jar"
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
StandardInput=tty-force
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
TTYPath=/dev/tty10
TTYVTDisallocate=yes
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The program waits for input in the tty, I can change to that tty by using Ctrl+Alt+F10 or using `chvt 10` and I'm able to interact with the program.

Now I want to send input and get output from that tty without changing my current tty.
I tried using `screen` and all I get is a blank screen and. I tried using `script` which succeeded if I run bash in that tty but fails If i run a java program

Answer (score 0):

The `PTY` feature of `socat` may be your best bet for interfacing terminal-heavy apps programmatically w/o any extra functionality. See the examples in the man page.

Also, `dtach` provides `screen`-like (multi-way) reattachment semantics for easy access from a terminal emulator.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `socat` to run on /dev/tty10? Also looking at  the man page of `dtach` I see no mention of `dtach` working with ttys, only sockets.