# How do I detach a process from its parent?

Tags: process, job-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)

The problem is that the process is not a job inside of my active shell (as I've logged in from remote because my X-system has crashed), meaning: I guess `disown`, `nohup`, `CTRL+Z` & `bg`, `screen` et al. will not work.

**Motivation:**
I started a long running job inside of a gnome-terminal. I want to detach it from the its parent, as I the X-system has crashed. I fear when I kill the X-system, also the Gnome Desktop + Gnome-Terminal + my precious script will be lost. So I still can login from remote and want to save the script process and restart X. How do I do that?

Comment: See e.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process  for an answer.

Comment: Please take a look at similar question at SuperUser  http://superuser.com/questions/1674/detach-and-reattach-xterms-across-x-sessions

Comment: @jofel: severfaults answer uses disown, which does not work for jobs outside of your current shell.

Comment: @hostmaster: The answer you selected could solve my problem but will only work for X-applications. I want it to work with _any_ application.

Comment: @Gilles: Did I said that screen does not work afterwards?

Comment: @math No, you wrote “I guess … screen et al. will not work”. I don't know why you guessed that, nor how you intended to use screen. Nonetheless, your situation is the same as that previous question: you have a process running in a terminal and you want to disconnect it from that terminal. Here the terminal is an X terminal emulator (Gnome-terminal) rather than sshd, but this doesn't change the answer. By the way, you should read [difference between a 'terminal', a 'shell' …](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4126) as you seem to be confusing the notions of *shell* and *terminal*.

Comment: @Gilles, convinced, you are right and the second part of your answer you gave in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell is really solving my problem. You could mark it as duplicate to this question.

Comment: @math I should have mentioned that the [2nd answer](http://serverfault.com/a/272526) on serverfaults about reptyr is what you need.

Comment: @all and I should have read more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the scripting language you use to run the job you could use

```
setpgrp()
Perl: setpgrp PID, PGRP
```

to detach the running process from the controlling terminal, so once it starts the controlling terminal can exit without harming the running process.

Now from what you are describing you will have the controlling terminal and shell by running Gnome Terminal and starting your job from there so `nohup` should work just fine for you.