# How to recover a backgrounded job from a previous shell?

Tags: bash, job-control, background-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)

I launched a command that lasts a long time.
I had to disconnect so I moved it in the background (with CTRL+Z and `bg`) before exiting.

Something like this:

```
$ my_command
***command is beeing executed and is taking a long time***
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 my_command
$ bg
[1]+ my_command &
$ exit
```

I reconnected and can see the command in the process list but cannot recover with `fg`.

```
$ fg
-bash: fg: current: no such job
```

How do I recover my job in the foreground?

Comment: Hm, the question linked from the possible-duplicate banner is arguably of lesser quality (it's inconsistent, i.e. it talks about pausing but also keeping it running in the background) and addresses a different situation, i.e. there OP hasn't already disconnected from the shell (an it's even unclear if the ssh connection needs to be terminated).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you've already started something somewhere, backgrounded it, and now need to attach it to a new terminal, you can use [`reptyr`](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) to re-attach it.  (The `man` page summarises the command as "Reparent a running program to a new terminal".)

The reason you can't see it in the "jobs" command or use "fg" to bring it to the foreground is because these commands are actually built-in to the shell. They don't technically detach the processes from the terminal you're connected with, so when you exit the shell they *should* exit as well (you should get a warning when you attempt to exit).

Comment: +1. thanks, i didn't know about `repytr`.  useful....doing what it does manually always seemed too much work to be worth the effort most of the time.

Comment: works so great... !!! thanks!!! sometimes you need to use 'sudo' to run the command. syntax: "sudo reptyr –s PID " and it brings my python process from other terminal active in the current one.

Comment: terminal closed unexpedtly while running wget. wget continued to provide log and new files. reptyr failed to bring it to terminal again: `sudo reptyr -s 783668
[-] Timed out waiting for child stop.
[-] Unable to open the tty in the child.
Unable to attach to pid 783668: Permission denied`

Comment: `reptyr -L PID` solved the above problem :)