# How to access the output of a process after the terminal was closed

Tags: linux, terminal, process, open-files

I started an application from the terminal which prints the status and various logs in the console so that I can read them from the terminal. I accidentally closed the terminal but the application is still running, however, I can't see the logs anymore. Is there a way to get back access to that process console which is still running. ?

I am on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.1 (Maipo).

I was running an application in *tornado*, a python framework using the following command.

```
python2.7 /proj/website/app.py 8080
```

8080 is the port number.

Comment: See [how to recover a backgrounded job from a previous shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49106/how-to-recover-a-backgrounded-job-from-a-previous-shell/49120#49120)

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the pid of the process `python` with `ps`, `pgrep` command.
2. Get the file discriptor of 1 (stdout) or 2 (stderr) /proc/*your_python_pid*/fd/{1,2}.

I found the similar post and link: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994593/how-to-reroute-stdout-stderr-back-to-dev-tty