# How do I attach myself to a process running in an inacessible terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, stdout, stdin

I have a process running in a terminal I'm unable to access due to that the X session it is running in is frozen. I would like to send some commands via stdin that tell it to stop before I kill the X session. I would also like to see stdout to verify that the command ran. How would I go about doing this?

To be clear: I do not have access to the terminal the process is running in and it is not running as a job.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover a backgrounded job from a previous shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49106/how-to-recover-a-backgrounded-job-from-a-previous-shell)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) can achieve this.

Using this syntax: `reptyr -Ts <pid>` I was able to attach myself to a process running in an inaccessible terminal and both see its stdout and write to its stdin (including executing what I had written).