# In linux, terminal closed unexpectally, but wget is continue to be run as process and to download (with proof). How I can bring it again to terminal?

Tags: wget, background-process

In linux, terminal closed unexpectedly, but wget continues to be run as process and to download --- with proof - new files generated from website -- weird enough, log chaged from given wget_log to wget-log which is updated continuously with new information about download.

How I can bring it again to terminal to show output?

Note that `jobs -l` shows nothing but in the  system monitor as a process, it exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover a backgrounded job from a previous shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49106/how-to-recover-a-backgrounded-job-from-a-previous-shell)

Comment: I will not take the risk now to experiment.... but i did a little experiment with  `reptyr -L pid` and it appears to work... thanks! https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell