# How to screen'ize already running session?

Tags: gnu-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)

It is a good practice to run long processes in `screen` session, to protect them from session hangups. But what should I do if I already have a process that is running and I just forgot to run `screen`? Is it possible to 'capture' current session somehow and protect it with `screen`?

Comment: Look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/184047/bash-zsh-undoing-disown) (and [here](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr)).

Comment: You could [use screen as your login shell](http://geekscrap.com/2010/02/using-screen-as-your-login-shell/) so this situation would not occur again (note that there're [caveats](http://alan.lamielle.net/2009/03/09/environment-variables-and-gnu-screen))

Answer (score 1):

You want to have a look at the retty program.  It's homepage is http://pasky.or.cz//dev/retty/

The idea is to redirect your stdin/stderr/stdout, which you can do with gdb, but this tiny program makes it much easier to do so.  It is not perfect, but should do the job.

Comment: Note that it's only for Linux and only some architectures (no amd64 for instance) and have more limitations than `reptyr` brought up by @angus.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the already mentioned [retty](http://pasky.or.cz/dev/retty/) and [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr), [neercs](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/neercs) and [injcode](http://www.habets.pp.se/synscan/programs.php?prog=injcode) offer the functionality as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

The closest you could get is:

Start a new screen window, run:

```
trap '' INT HUP
exec sleep 99999999
```

in it. Record the tty for that window (`$tty`).

Use `lsof` to figure out what fds of what processes in the session are open to the current tty.

With gdb, attach to every process in the session, do some `call signal(1,1)` to ignore the SIGHUPs. For the session leader, you'll probably need to do a `call dup2(0,1023)` (assuming 0 is opened on the tty) to keep a fd open on the old terminal. Then for each process, do

```
set variable $fd = open("the-screen-window-tty",2)
```

Then for each fd that was open on the old terminal, do:

```
call dup2($fd, that-fd)
```

And then:

```
call close($fd)
detach
```

The session attached to the new terminal would be the one with that "sleep" process as the leader (and only process) though, things like window resizing, CTRL-C, CTRL-Z, job control, /dev/tty won't work and probably a few more nasty side effects I don't think of.

If on Linux, [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr), brought up by @angus in a comment to your question, automates that process and addresses the shortcomings above by creating a new pty and make that controlled by the process you want to migrate. However, it only supports migrating one process AFAICT.