# End process from another SSH window

Tags: ssh, terminal, process, signals, process-management

I forgot to use `screen` and I have a task that has been running for quite some time, and I do not want to lose the saved data. Basically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> will end the task and save the data if I am on the same terminal session, is there a way to stop it in different SSH window?

I do not have access to the same terminal window at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

C-c sends `SIGINT` to the foreground process group, you can kill it using `kill` on the foreground process group id (see `ps -ej` output).

```
kill -s INT -- -pgid
```

Comment: thanks i will remember this next time, I just tried to ssh in and the system rebooted so I lost the data :|

Answer (score 2):

There are several utilities that are able to change the tty of a running process. Most of them written exactly for the purpose of attaching a running process into a terminal multiplexer - see e.g.:

- [How to screen'ize already running session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56298/how-to-screenize-already-running-session/)
- [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell/)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process