# Can I transfer running process from dead ssh

Tags: bash, shell, process, job-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)

I have started  (as expected) a long copy process from ssh shell (putty) which died due to client problem. What I see now is that process is still actively running, but I have no way to control it, since my shell died:

```
# w
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    192.168.X.Y   15:35    2:03m  4:39   4:39  cp -i -a source/ /data/
...
#
```

Now I am wondering if I could somehow transfer this process to my new ssh terminal (or screen).

Answer (score 0):

[Reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) does what you need:

> reptyr is a utility for taking an existing running program and attaching it to a new terminal. Started a long-running process over ssh, but have to leave and don't want to interrupt it? Just start a screen, use reptyr to grab it, and then kill the ssh session and head on home.