# How can I rejoin a process running

Tags: python, pid

I am very new to using Linux.  I have a 'machine' on Amazon and I was trying to learn how to use Python on this machine.  I started running Python—had to step away for a few minutes and the connection was reset.  I rejoined the connection and started wondering if the Python process was running.  I poked around and submitted the

```
ps -ewwo pid,args | grep python
```

and I discovered all of this

```
root@mymachine:/# ps -ewwo pid,args | grep python
906 python
1118 grep python
2450 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/mailman/bin/mailmanctl -q start
2451 /usr/bin/python /var/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=ArchRunner:0:1 -s
2452 /usr/bin/python /var/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=BounceRunner:0:1 -s
2453 /usr/bin/python /var/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=CommandRunner:0:1 -s
2456 /usr/bin/python /var/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=IncomingRunner:0:1 -s
2462 /usr/bin/python /var/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=NewsRunner:0:1 -s
2468 /usr/bin/python /var/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=OutgoingRunner:0:1 -s
2469 /usr/bin/python /var/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=VirginRunner:0:1 -s
2470 /usr/bin/python /var/lib/mailman/bin/qrunner --runner=RetryRunner:0:1 -s
```

From what I have found I think that Python is still running and it has a process ID of 906.

I would like to know

1. Will it die on its own at some point (not likely from what I understand)
2. Can I rejoin it somehow?
3. Am I even correct in my conclusion and if I can't rejoin it can I kill it?

Comment: You can try “rejoining” the process (i.e. attaching it to your current terminal), but it doesn't always work. See [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will it die on its own at some point (not likely from what I understand)

Not unless Amazon has some daemon set up to do that sort of thing.

> Can I rejoin it somehow?

<s>Nope.</s> **EDIT**: Looks like the program [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) can do it, but it's not a standard command, so you'll have to install it yourself.

> ... and if I can't rejoin it can I kill it?

Yes.  If `killall` is available, and this is Linux, you can just do `killall python`, or `pkill python` if it isn't available.  If that doesn't kill them, you can do `killall -KILL`, `pkill -KILL`, or `kill -KILL` instead to force them to die.