# Call background process back to stdout

Tags: bash, process, background-process, stdout

Is it possible to "call" a background process output to be shown in the terminal?

Example: cron starts apt-get to update the system and I want to see the output of apt-get

Answer (score 2):

Not really. There are tools that can detach a process from its output file and attach it to the current terminal — see [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell). However:

- These tools operate via a debugging interface ([`ptrace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace)) and modify the execution of the program in an underhanded way. This can crash some programs.
- If it works, the output will be on the terminal instead of the log file where it's supposed to go, not in addition to the log file.
- The output emitted before running the tool will be in the log file only.

The output of a cron job will be logged somewhere: either the script in the crontab redirects the output to a file, or cron will send the output to the administrator by email. Check the crontab entry to see where the output goes.

On Linux, you can check where the output of a process goes by looking at its file descriptors in `/proc/PID/fd/`. File descriptor 1 is standard output and 2 is standard error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. That would assume the process knows how to handle this situation and would reopen stdin/stdout/stderr.