# SSH pipe broke while running apt upgrade. What can I do about it?

Tags: debian, ssh, apt, aptitude

I was connected to my aws debian wheezy server and while running `apt-get upgrade` the ssh pipe broke. I didn't use `screen` or anything, so I don't think there's a way to recover that session.

If I reconnect with a new ssh session and run `ps aux | grep apt`, I can see that `apt` and `dpkg` are [still running](http://cl.ly/Xd44)

They've been running for hours actually. I can't imagine that it would be safe to kill those processes as they might be modifying system libs/binaries, but what can I do? What if they are waiting for keyboard input or the like? I had said `y` when `apt` originally asked me to install the updates, but I don't know if it needed further user input. I plan on waiting a few more hours for `dpkg` and apt to hopefully complete what they're doing.. but if nothing happens, what are my options?

Comment: I personally always use `tmux` over SSH, so I could never encounter such a problem. GNU `screen` or `dtach` should both be good alternatives.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work, but you might be able to bring the processes back to the foreground with `fg`.

Comment: I think fg and bg only work for attached processes started in the current tty session ("jobs")

Comment: Can't you reattach to the process using gdb?

Answer (score 3):

You can't regain the session. And so you cannot do anything to interact with that process.

I don't think the process is running. I guess the `apt-get` might have become a *zombie* by now. Anyway you can check the process using `ps` or `top`. If it's running, then let go and monitor it to finish. If it stays idle just kill it.

And then you can simply run `apt-get upgrade` **once again** after killing the process, to finish or repair any package being upgraded while the session crashed.

Comment: On my Pi 5, the subsequent `apt-get upgrade` gave me the error `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.`
Just run that if you see the error. Personally, I'm running `sudo apt-get upgrade` again after `dpkg` to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is ok to send them a `SIGINT` (keyboard interruption, i.e. Ctrl+C) signal:

```
killall -SIGINT apt-get
```

or

```
killall -2 apt-get
```

You may also try to do it twice or more

Comment: did that a few times but with no effect :(

Comment: Killing it with -SIGTERM worked for me, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try to [reattach the session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell) with a tool like [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr), but that doesn't always work.

You can kill `apt`, `dpkg` and their subprocesses at any time. All package maintenance tasks are supposed to resist a sudden power failure. Run the command again to complete it.

Make sure to send a SIGINT or SIGTERM signal to APT and dpkg, not a SIGKILL. A SIGKILL would leave lock files in place. This is a general principle: don't use SIGKILL when SIGINT would do.

Comment: > All package maintenance tasks are supposed to resist a sudden power failure
I don't know about latest debian versions, but with debian 4-5 I had got into a trouble supposing this

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to do better in the future: use 'screens'

This Debian post helped me to fix my acute problem:

https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ

```
sudo fuser -vki -TERM /var/lib/dpkg/lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend

sudo dpkg --configure --pending
```