# How do I get the output of a program already running?

Tags: linux, bash, python, io-redirection

I have a python program that outputs to `stdout` and a log file.

However, the person I am making this for wants to know if I can set it up so that he can see the output of the file, while it is running on a different terminal or in the background. For example the program launched at startup, and he wants to `ssh` into it and see the output it is running.

So is there a way to see the output of a process that is currently running?

Preferably in bash or python, if possible.

Comment: If it ouputs into a log file, he could do a `tail -f file.log`?

Comment: I agree with @fredtantini, I use `tail` to watch a certain file, but I also use `watch` if I know there are multiple files in that folder that I want to keep an eye on.

Comment: See [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4034/15241)

Comment: Problem with that screen is that requires keyboard input from my understanding, which is something I can't do as the program is meant to go on a headless server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two options. One, he can use `tail -f` to see the log file as it's being written, or two, he can have the program start inside a `screen` (or similar) session to which he can (re-)attach later.

If he doesn't know the location of the log file, he can use `top`, `ps` or a similar tool to find the process ID, then run `lsof -p1234` where 1234 is the process id to list the open files of that process.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer using `less` to do this same thing.

```
less your_file
```

After starting `less`, the <kbd>F</kbd> command (not a command line flag) will begin to actively monitor the end of the file. While watching the end of the file in this mode <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> will stop appending output to `less` and allow you to page around. Very handy.