# Pipe output of process that's already running

Tags: process, pipe

I've got a process that spews out a lot of output, and it's going to be running for the next hour. I forgot to pipe its output through my `awk` script before I started running it. Now my terminal is full of things that make it hard to read.

Is there a way I can background the process, then resume it in the foreground with its output being piped through my script before going to the terminal?

Comment: This is close to [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell), and some of the solutions there might work for you. I'm not voting to close as a duplicate because switching to a pipe and to a terminal aren't exactly the same and some solutions may work for the one but not for the other.