# Does overlayfs redirect opened files automatically on the fly?

Tags: mount, overlayfs

or I should close file - then mount overlay - and then re-open file again?
i.e.

```
#!/bin/bash
my_background_process >log.txt &
...
pkill my_background_process
mount overlay
my_background_process >>log.txt &
...
```

is it necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a file is open, it stays open until the process closes it. Reading and writing from a file don't care whether the file is still available under its original name. The file may have been renamed, deleted, shadowed… it's still the same file.

If you open a file `/somewhere/somefile` then mount a filesystem at `/somewhere`, then after that point `/somewhere/somefile` will designate a file on the new filesystem. But that only matters when you open `/somewhere/somefile`. If a process already had `/somewhere/somefile` open on the original filesystem, that doesn't change.

Redirection opens a file when the shell processes the redirection operator. After that, it keeps being the same open file, even if multiple processes are involved. For example, in the snippet below, `program2` writes to the file at `/mnt/log.txt` on the root partition, whereas `program3` writes to `/log.txt` on `/dev/something`.

```
do_stuff () {
  program1
  mount /dev/something /mnt
  program2
  program3 >/mnt/log.txt
}
do_stuff >/mnt/log.txt
```

If you've already started a program and you want to change where its output goes, you need to ask the program to do it. In theory, you can force the program to do it using a debugger — [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell) lists some programs that can do it. But getting down and dirty with a program like this can crash it.

If you really need to change where the program's output goes midway, you need to relay the output through a helper that is able to change its own output. Here's a tiny proof-of-concept in a shell script:

```
my_background_process | {
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line" >>/mnt/log.txt
  done
} &
```

This script opens the output file for each line, so if the file designated by `/mnt/log.txt` changes (because the file has been moved, because a new filesystem has been mounted at `/mnt`, etc.) then the subsequent lines will be written to the new file. Note that you need to specify the name of the directory: with just `>log.txt`, this would always open the file in the current directory, so it wouldn't be affected by a mount operation (the current directory works like an open file: mounting something on `/mnt` doesn't affect what processes see as their current directory even if their current directory is `/mnt`).

Answer (score 0):

There is no support in Linux for automatically redirecting files which were opened on an arbitrary filesystem.  It is necessary to do so yourself.