# How can I open a VIM process with one user (using su) and then access with another user?

Tags: linux, vim

I want to open a VIM instance with one user account (using su), then login as another user and access the same session with that user.

Example User1:
su - user2 -c vim somefile.txt

Then I want to login as User2 and then access that VIM process created by that first user. I know it's possible but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: So, you want to open an interactive process (VIM) with one user, and then access with another user? Question: why does the first user have to use su, but not the second one?

Comment: `tmux` or `screen` are your best bets.  alternately, `disown` or `reptyr` or other tricks might be used.  see https://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell or a myriad of similar questions.  the only difference here is running the initial process as a different user; personally i'd use `su` with `tmux`.