# Monitor Process Output For Scripts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scripting, terminal, job-control

Is there a way to view the console outputs of a particular script that is running in the background on a machine?

Maybe using the pid or something similar.

For example, to view the output of this script

script.pm

```
while (1) {
  print "OUTPUT\n"
}
```

**Example Usage**

-> ps ax | grep script.pm

<- 1234 ?        S      0:05 /var/lib/script.pm

-> monitor 1234    #this is a fake command

<- OUTPUT

<- OUTPUT

<- OUTPUT

<- OUTPUT

<- OUTPUT

Comment: Why not just redirect the output of the background script to a file and then monitor the output of the file?

Comment: it's for a mojo server spread across many files in deployment and I'm trying to see at any level where errors are occurring, or just general diagnostic output. @RamanSailopal

Comment: I agree with @RamanSailopal, you'll want to ship STDOUT and STDERR from your application to a log file, and then up to a log ingestion server that can process and query the logs from all the different application servers. Look into the ELK stack or Graylog.

Comment: maybe [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) can help. Also, take a look at [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4034/how-can-i-disown-a-running-process-and-associate-it-to-a-new-screen-shell)

Answer (score 0):

If the process is running in the background, you can move it to the foreground of your current shell with the [`fg`](https://ss64.com/bash/fg.html) command. The processes output will then start writing to your shell.

If you want to send the process back to the background, you can press `CTRL+Z` to suspend the process, then the [`bg`](https://ss64.com/bash/bg.html) command to send it back to the background.

Usage: 
`fg PID`
`bg PID`

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a way to view the console outputs of a particular script that is running in the background on a machine?*

There is now, via a brand new utility called [`pw` (Pipe Watch)](https://www.kylheku.com/cgit/pw/about/).

How it would go is like this. We redirect the output of the script to `pw`, and put it into the background:

```
$ script.pm | pw &
[1] 1234
```

Now both the script and `pw` are executing in the background. `pw` is reading the output. It is aware that it is executing as a member of a background process group of a job control shell, and consequently refrains from trying to display anything on the terminal.

Then, at any time we feel like it, we do this:

```
$ fg
```

to bring the job to the foreground. Now `pw` activates its interactive display, which is being refreshed with the script's output.

When we don't want to look at that any more, then we can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to instruct `pw` to suspend itself, and then `bg` command will resume the background execution.