# Mistakenly started a long running task on an ssh shell

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux, gnu-screen, nohup

I understand that a long-running job on a server should be started with nohup/screen/tmux. But sometimes by mistake, I will start a job w/o realizing how long it would take. For example, I recently issued a move command (in an ssh shell) from a physically mounted directory to a network-mounted one (w/o knowing the second one was a network mount).

What is the solution for this besides babysitting the ssh shell?

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4034/315749

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the terminal running the `mv` you can do:

1. Press Ctrl+Z.
2. `bg`

And, that will continue the execution of the move in the background.
As a side note; If you suspend/background a lot, then you may want to run `jobs` after the Ctrl+Z and get the number of the `mv` job so you background the right job (e.g. `bg 1`.)

Hope that helps.