# how to put an existing process into an interactive shell's foreground

Tags: bash, process, nohup, job-control, reptyr

Say I started a long running process with `nohup`. As predicted, I close the current shell session. I open a new one and then I would like to add the still running process to the foreground (or to the background of the current shell's job control, which ultimately is the same as I could then move it to the foreground.)

Are tools like `reptyr` the way to go? Or is there a more traditional/recommended way?

Comment: If you can control how you start the process, then use `screen`/`tmux`. If not, then yes, you will have to user `reptyr`, or other such tools (see, e.g., the list in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4035/70524)